# Exclamation(!) operator used on a number in vb.net, what does this do?

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking at inherited code and I found this in a vb.net windows form:

```
New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
```

My question is, what is the significance of the `!` (exclamation) operator here? Most of my searching for the exclamation operator ends up returning recordset format or the `!` gets ignored in the search and I get hundreds of unrelated items.

Answer (score 11):

It's to force the literal to be a Single.

Visual Basic supports [Type Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> In addition to specifying a data type in a declaration statement, you can force the data type of some programming elements with a type character. The type character must immediately follow the element, with no intervening characters of any kind.

and:

> Literals can also use the identifier type characters (%, &, @, !, #, $), as can variables, constants, and expressions. However, the literal type characters (S, I, L, D, F, R, C) can be used only with literals.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the `!` stands for [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx):

> Type Characters. Appending the literal type character F to a literal forces it to the Single data type. **Appending the identifier type character ! to any identifier forces it to Single**.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

It is a type character.  It means that 6.0 is a Single data type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx show the type characters.