# Trailing Ampersand in VB.NET hexadecimal?

Tags: vb.net, hex

This should be an easy one for folks.  Google's got nothing except content farms linking to one blurb, and that's written in broken English.  So let's get this cleared up here where it'll be entombed for all time.

What's the trailing ampersand on VB hexadecimal numbers for?  I've read it forces conversion to an Int32 on the chance VB wants to try and store as an Int16.  That makes sense to me.  But the part I didn't get from the blurb was to always use the trailing ampersand for bitmasks, flags, enums, etc.  Apparantly, it has something to do with overriding VB's fetish for using signed numbers for things internally, which can lead to weird results in comparisons.

So to get easy points, what are the rules for VB.Net hexadecimal numbers, with and without the trailing ampersand?  Please include the specific usage in the case of bitmasks/flags and such, and how one would also use it to force signed vs. unsigned.

No C# please :)

Comment: It's a [Type Character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek(v=vs.80).aspx). There was another question on here recently [about them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732943/exclamation-operator-used-on-a-number-in-vb-net-what-does-this-do).

Comment: Ah, I always forget about those.  Like "UL" in C.  You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @kumba - would have been nice to see an example of what you were looking at.

Comment: @dbasnett: Not everything needs an example, I felt I gave enough of a description for someone to visualize.  But, `&HFFF0&` is an example.

Comment: @kumba  It never hurts.  These are two entirely different things; Dim i As Integer = &HFFFF0&  and Dim l As Long = &HFFFF0&

Comment: @dbasnett: True...one of the confusions that haunt VB's syntax.  C's `0xFFF0UL` is so much more clearer.

Comment: @kumba VB can be Dim l As Long = &HFFFF0L or  Dim ul As ULong = &HFFFF0UL

Comment: What would you expect "Dim L as Long = &hCAFEBABE" to yield?  The answer is &hFFFFFFFFCAFEBABE&.  How about "&h00000000CAFEBABE"?  The answer is still &hFFFFFFFFCAFEBABE&.  One needs a trailing ampersand (or other type specifier) to write values between &h0000000080000000& and &h00000000FFFFFFFF&.  Curiously, it's not needed for values outside that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Basic has the concept of [Type Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). These can be used to modify variable declarations and literals, although I'd not recommend using them in variable declarations - most developers are more familiar these days with `As`. E.g. the following declarations are equivalent:

```
Dim X&
Dim X As Long
```

But personally, I find the second more readable. If I saw the first, I'd actually have to go visit the link above, or use Intellisense, to work out what the variable is (not good if looking at the code on paper).

Comment: Aye, I guess I just switch into another mode when I see the literals on a non-decimal number.  You start Hex out with an ampersand, so having the trailing ampersand can play with your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Vb.net will regard "&h"-notation hex constants in the range from 0x80000000-0xFFFFFFFF as negative numbers unless the type is explicitly specified as UInt32, Int64, or UInt64.  Such behavior might be understandable if the numbers were written with precisely eight digits following the "&", but for some reason I cannot fathom, *vb.net will behave that way even if the numbers are written with leading zeroes*.  In present versions of VB, one may force the number to be evaluated correctly by using a suffix of "&" suffix (Int64), "L" (Int64), "UL" (UInt64), or "UI" (UInt32).  In earlier versions of VB, the "problem range" was 0x8000-0xFFFF, and the only way to force numbers in that range to be evaluated correctly (as a 32-bit integer, which was then called a "Long") was a trailing ampersand.